Why does a rod move faster when struck at the center rather than the edge, despite Newton's second law indicating the same acceleration?"
When applying the same force to the edge or the center of a rod, according to Newton's second law, the rod will acquire the same acceleration in both cases. That is, the speed the rod acquires in both cases should be the same. However, in reality, I notice that any object, when I strike it at the center, gains more speed than when I strike it at the edge. When I strike it at the center, it doesn't rotate much or perhaps not at all, and it moves faster. But when I strike it at the edge, it rotates quickly but moves slower.
Could someone explain a perspective that might correct my understanding.

Rotation vs translation motion - where it is hit determines how much energy goes into each.

We see, however, that Newton's second law applies to all bodies and does not take into account the location where the force acts on the body.

Yes, but you still trade off rotation vs translation if you don’t strike through the center of mass. The second law applies, certainly. You apply force to spin something, just like to translate something.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/814423/174766

This might help - Toppling of a cylinder on a block

Thank you all. Every comment or link you recommended played a role in the topic and helped me realize my misconception.

@BezinaTaki [Newton's second law] does not take into account the location where the force acts on the body Second Newton law for rotational motion has form $$\tag 1 \tau = I \alpha,$$ and torque as such does take into account force application position as per $$\tag 2 \vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F.$$

"the rod will acquire the same acceleration" actually the correct statement is "the rod center of mass will acquire the same acceleration".

The point that is missing in the question (and hidden in the answers) is that by hitting a rod in different points, you aren't applying the same force nor applying it during the same time.

I think it is the contact time between the force and the rod that causes the real world experience to differ from theory. When struck at its center (of mass), an object is able to stay in touch with the source of the force longer than when struck elsewhere. During the latter, the induced rotation breaks contact more quickly. There are two effects:

The longer contact time leads to larger momentum transfer ($\Delta \vec p =\int \vec F dt$) and larger energy transfer ($\Delta E=\int \vec F.\vec vdt$)

usually, an applied force drops in magnitude once contact begins to break. A longer contact time leads to a steady force being applied longer.


In theory, the instantaneous force and torque are most generally modeled as a $\delta$-function linear/angular impulse and wouldn't account for the contact time (unless differently normalized).
This is only a hypothesis and needs data to substantiate. One experimental design choice is to make the contact time independent of or negligibly small compared to the motion of the object. Another is to use non-contact forces.
The induced rotational motion is in addition to the translational motion and has little bearing on why the object doesn't translate as far (in the real world). To repeat, torque is induced in addition to the applied force. No translational energy is "stolen" by the rotation, it is provided in addition by the source (that would be the case if the energy imparted to the rod was the same in both cases - center and edge - which I think is not)

Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.

While I do like this particular investigation where the application time might not be the same, I was under the impression that the "fundamental reason" here is that Newton's laws as such only apply to point masses or, as a generalisation, to center of mass of a system. So the reason for the surprising result would be in wrong assumptions. I will try to source this better today.

The total momentum that you are exchanging is likely not the same in each case.

Strike in the center.
Because the force applied is in line with the center of mass, all the mass must be dragged along before any noticeable motion occurs.

Strike the edge. The applied force is NOT in line with the center of mass. The requirement that all mass must be dragged along before any noticeable motion happens no longer applies. This makes the object feel "lighter" than what it really is. The fact that it is rotating also eats up energy that could have been used for forward motion.


Depending on material of the rod, and material of the striker, Case 1 almost certainly has more kinetic energy by the end of the strike compared to case 2 assuming the strike mechanism identical. There is slightly less opportunity for momentum to be exchanged because in case 2 the object "gets out of the way" faster.
Although I would be curious on more concrete examples on what exact objects you are talking about and what you are hitting them with.

First, thank you for your answer, and I agree with everything you said. However, note that Newton's second law does not depend on the point of application of the force on the rod. Its result is that the rod will move with the same speed after being applied the same force, whether the force is applied at the center or at the edge, which is not what we observe in reality.

How do you know that the force is the same between the two cases? What exactly is doing the pushing in your thought experiment? There is less inertia to overcome in case two. If you are just pushing it with your hand the force is likely much less than case 1.
You are right, F=ma doesn't mention anything about the point of application. That is a limitation of it. It doesn't mean that later in the field you don't have to consider the point of application. F=ma is assuming the force is applied to the center of mass, and it gives you the resulting acceleration.

What is the proof that a force applied on a rigid body will cause it to rotate around its center of mass? and Appendix 20 A Chasles’s Theorem: Rotation and Translation of a Rigid
Body in the MIT 8.01 Mechanics textbook.

@BezinaTaki The force you calculated is the same for both center and off-center strikes. Every time you hit the rod, your strike induces an impulse of linear and rotational energy. The more centered the strike, the less rotational energy.  The total energy between both rotation + linear is the energy your strike imparts. When off-center, a greater amount of the strike energy is split into the rotational element, which reduces the available energy to move forward, resulting in a slower linear movement speed. 100% of the rotation you observe is speed not put into forward movement.

One word explains why your ideal world analysis disagrees with your real world observation - friction.
Ideal world analysis
Linear acceleration of centre of mass of the rod is the same irrespective of where the rod is hit.
Angular acceleration about centre of mass is greater when the applied force applies a larger torque about the centre of mass, ie force is applied at right angles to the rod and further from the centre of mass.
Real world observation
Contradicts theory, as explained above, because of the presence of friction and so much so that many think the theoretical analysis is flawed.
In some ways this is like the old idea that a force needed to be applied to a cart (or any other object) to keep it moving at constant velocity.
A series of YouTube videos made by Veritasium which is similar to the rod experiment with very little friction.
The Bullet Block Experiment
Bullet Block Experiment Result
Bullet Block Explained!

Thank you very much. Your comment and the videos you recommended were very important in correcting my perspective.

Congratulations @Farcher on reaching 100k!

The first observation is that when you strike an object along its center of mass, you use a higher force than when striking it some offset distance from the center of mass. This is why you observe different accelerations.
The reason is that when striking an object you are imparting an impulse and not a force. Impulse can be thought as the product of force and time, or in rough terms
$$ J = F\, \Delta t $$
where $J$ is the impacting impulse and $F$ is the average force applied over a period of time $\Delta t$.
Impulse $J$ has units of momentum and for in impacting ball, for example, it is equal to the momentum of the ball $J = m v$.
In any case, for the sake of this argument, consider the impulse $J$ known, and then the force seen by the object is
$$ F = \frac{J}{\Delta t}$$
If the body is rotating due to the impact, then the objects will be in contact for a longer period of time than if the object just bounced off. When $\Delta t$ is larger , then $F$ is smaller.
And the magnitude of $F$ determines the acceleration of the center of mass o the body
$$ a = \frac{F}{M} $$

Thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Let us say that there is a heavy mass with high velocity impacting a rod laid on the ground. Newton's second Law is for a particle and force applied on it when the force is applied at its CG, resulting in translation alone.
Energy conservation principle gives more information about distribution of PE and KE, the potential and kinetic energies. The rod stuck at its end has both PE and KE, and rotational KE slows down the translational speed.
